Setting a max runtime for an optimiser
I'm using the Matlab Optimisation toolbox to create and solve an optimisation problem which I have called chargeprob.
After running my code successfully, I want to implement a maximum calculation time.
options = optimoptions("linprog","MaxTime",5)
[sol,fval,exitflag,output] = solve(chargeprob,'Options',options)

If my understanding is correct this should mean that if the solve takes longer than 5 seconds, the solver should exit saying no solution was found in time. Instead what happens is that it appears to have no effect with the solver taking in this case 30 seconds. What is the correct way to set a timeout on my solver?

From the documentation it looks like the MaxTime option only applies if you're using a Dual-Simplex Algorithm (Highs or Legacy). Did you try with one of those set? Otherwise you could approximate how long each iteration is taking and use MaxIterations instead, which is applicable to all algos

I can set it to "Dual Simplex" using options.Algorithm = "dual-simplex"but this produces the same result is there a way to set it to Highs? I'm aware i can use use max iterations and i might have to but max time would be an ideal
